# How to get distinct column value by using Editor Templates in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How to get distinct column value by using Editor Templates in MVC4?

I tried below code in Editortemplates..It returns duplicate column value. But I want this code o return distinct column value

Can anyone help me please?

```
@model mvcdemo.Models.profile
<div id="chkbx-editor">
@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.profile_id)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.isselected)
@Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.profile_field)
</div>
```

Comment: How are you using your `EditorTemplate`? Include your view.

Comment: Hi thanks for your immediate response!..I have to display column value(profile field) from Model. So I used Editor Template to retrieve profile_field value from my Model class. My view  contain this code only since it needs to be display profile_field alone.

Comment: What do you mean by _"It returns duplicate column value"_

Comment: There are several project in the same tower. By optionally one project profile field value will be display as checkbox list. The other project people will select profile field from checkbox list if they want..and selected profile_field value will be inserted into the same table with respect to their project_id. So when i run the code after this, it displays same profile_field twice...

Comment: How much time it selected, that much time in replicate same profile_field value. But i want to only display distinct column value only...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the solution. I posted here how i got it.

In controller class, use the below code:

```
var tbllist = new List<Sampleprofile>();
int numRows = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
{
    string tbl = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].Field<string>("profile_filed");
    tbllist.Add(new profile() { profile_filed = tbl});
}

return View(tbllist);
```